# How to add actual column name as alias name in a Case Expression

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL 10 which has a couple of columns of `boolean` type. In the select query, I want to cast the value to 1/0 instead of t/f and for blank value keep it blank.

Tried, **boolean_col::int** syntax but that still wasn't casting. The reason as per Postgres Doc,

> Values of the boolean type cannot be cast directly to other types (e.g., CAST (boolval AS integer) does not work). This can be accomplished using the CASE expression: CASE WHEN boolval THEN 'value if true' ELSE 'value if false' END.

So tried using Case Expression, got expected result but now column name is printed as Case I want actual column name to printed and so used alias syntax but that is working only if I give anything but actual column name and I want to print alias name same as the actual column name.

```
SELECT
 (case when column1 then 1 else 0 end) as "column1" ,(case when column1 then '' else '' end ) as "column1" 
 ,(case when column2 then 1 else 0 end) as "column2" , (case when column2 then '' else '' end) as "column2"
FROM tablename
```

Actual Result:

```
Case  Case
1      0
       1
0
```

Expected Result:

```
column1    column2
1           0
            1
0
```

Comment: That is not true. Your query will use `column1` and `column2` as alias names.

Comment: `boolean_col::int` works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6f2e8acd9cd7d434973194fe53b2f9e2

Comment: What you are quoting is the docs from version 8.0 or earlier.  That was a very long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
(case when column1 then 1 else 0 end as "column1")
```

Comment: that fails with  ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"

Comment: Remove the useless parentheses

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing it:

```
create table bool_test (column1 bool, column2 bool);
CREATE TABLE
insert into bool_test values ('t', 'f'), ('f', 'f'), ('t', 't');

SELECT
 (case when column1 then 1 else 0 end) as "column1" ,(case when column1 then '' else '' end ) as "column1" 
 ,(case when column2 then 1 else 0 end) as "column2" , (case when column2 then '' else '' end) as "column2"
FROM bool_test;

 column1 | column1 | column2 | column2 
---------+---------+---------+---------
       1 |         |       0 | 
       0 |         |       0 | 
       1 |         |       1 | 
(3 rows)
```

There must be something else going on you have not shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for your valuable input. The query which I was using and the ones which were shared by some of you where the valid ones, issue was in Client tool (IDE) earlier I was using the DBeaver tool which was somehow not giving expected results. But later I tried same query in another tool Heidisql there it gave actual result.